# Adding extra rows to tibble /dataframes by ID combination with formula (or Time series like operations on tidy tibble)

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tibble

Certain time-series operations seem to be less intuitive to complete in a tidy data form in R than they would be either with matrices arrays or with a wide form (with years one of the dimensions) eg in Excel. For example, I would like to add 2035 data as a function of previous emissions
Emissions_2035=Emissions_2030+(Emissions_2030-Emissions_2025)
but in the 'tidy' data form below. ((Or I might want a 'lagged operator' for tibbles with years as one of the ID variables.)) How could I create an easy consistent way of adding 2035 data for each sector/region combination?

Do I need some sort of time series object to do this?

```
Emissions = tribble(
~Sector, ~CountryOrRegion,~Year, ~Emissions,
"Transport","Africa","2025","452627",
"Transport","Africa","2030","546313",
"Buildings","Africa","2025","52627",
"Buildings","Africa","2030","46313",
"Transport","Europe","2025","652627",
"Transport","Europe","2030","746313",
#etc...
)
```

Desired output:

```
Emissions = tribble(
~Sector, ~CountryOrRegion,~Year, ~Emissions,
"Transport","Africa","2025","452627",
"Transport","Africa","2030","546313",
"Transport","Africa","2035","641234",
"Buildings","Africa","2025","52627",
"Buildings","Africa","2030","46313",
"Buildings","Africa","2035","41234",
"Transport","Europe","2025","652627",
"Transport","Europe","2030","746313",
"Transport","Europe","2035","841234",
#etc...

)
```

Comment: Do you have data of only two years (2025 and 2030) and want to create data of only 2035 ?

Comment: No this data is huge. THere's mytiple sectors, regions and in general I want an operation to work sequentially emissions t are a function of emissions t-1 e_(t)= f(e_(t-1))

Comment: Can you increase the rows in sample dataset with at least 2 groups and 4-5 rows in each group and show the corresponding output for it?

Comment: I've done that now

Comment: My answer does work for this new data. Although, the numbers differ. Are you showing only dummy numbers in the output? If not, how did you calculate it ?

Comment: Sorry yes I used fake data, not the real outcome. Thanks so much for an amazing answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try -

```
library(dplyr)

#change character to numbers
Emissions <- Emissions %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE) 

Emissions %>%
  arrange(Sector, CountryOrRegion, Year) %>%
  group_by(Sector, CountryOrRegion) %>%
  summarise(Year = 2035,
            Emissions = last(Emissions) + diff(Emissions), .groups = 'drop')  %>%
  bind_rows(Emissions) %>%
  arrange(Sector, CountryOrRegion, Year)
```

Comment: That's vlever. So does diff just work like magic? And how? Does it somehow take the previous row of the same ID variables that are in the 'current row' of the grouping operation? Or does it rely on it being sorted by the ID variables (so the last row (in most cases) is the year before).